# Nine Tall Men Are Standing Tall

Tags: riddle

This one may turn out to be a little too easy but I really enjoyed writing the Seussian rhymes.

> Nine tall men are standing tall. Nine tall men here all in all.
>   As they talk amongst each other, "Wait!" they hear, "There is another!"
>   In walks Sergeant Bleighterfest. "There is another!" he protests.
>   "Nothing's missing" says the crew. "We're all here. What's wrong with you?"
>   "He is the youngest - I'll admit - but he's important, every bit."
>   "Bah," they say, "We know that slob. He is useless at our job.
>   He sulks and hides and rarely talks. He's certainly no chatterbox."
>   "Is that a reason to exclude? To mock and joke and be so rude?
>   By himself he is not much," admits the Sergeant to the bunch.
>   "Everyone must help him be all that I know that he can be.
>   I know his task he will not shirk but, without you, he cannot work!"
>   Here the Sergeant paused to think where could that little guy have slinked?
>   Snorkeling at Sharktooth Reef? I've never held such disbelief!
>   Diving off our tallest peak? That cannot be the place I seek.
>   Wait a minute, I'm so dense! I needn't be in such suspense.
>   "If he's gone – walked out the door – he's even more here than before!"
>   It was just then he realized the last had been here all the time.
>   The Sergeant spun until he spotted the space for little one allotted
>   Filled now - someone's in the spot. "There you are, you silly ___________!"

**- Who was missing?

 - How would you fill in the blank line at the end?

 - Can you find the other group members hiding in the riddle?**

Comment: Wow! [No results!](https://www.google.com/search?q=Bleighterfest&oq=Bleighterfest&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60l2.167j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Curmudgeon I tried to think of a Seussian name. I supposed I succeeded?

Comment: @EngineerToast: Exactly my point! Great name choice. Although it looks like Google already found us out -- this post is now the only result :p

Comment: @Curmudgeon Does this mean I'm famous?

Comment: @EngineerToast: Basically, yep. Send an email to Google now that they know who you are and nab a job!

Comment: Cool idea. Nice puzzle!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The hiding of the "nine tall men" within the rhyme is genius!

The rhyme ends with:

> "There you are, you silly naught!"

The nine tall men are

> The digits from 1 to 9

The missing "person" is

> The digit 0
>
>  By itself, a zero can't do much; it needs the other digits to "do its work."

The other nine are highlighted below (#6 is backwards and spans 2 lines -- thanks, @mmking!):

> Nine tall men are standing tall. **Nine** tall men here all in all.
>  As they talk amongst each other, "Wait!" they hear, "There is another!"
>  In walks Sergeant Bl**eight**erfest. "There is another!" he protests.
>  "Nothing's missing" says the crew. "We're all here. What's wrong with you?"
>  "He is the youngest - I'll admit - but he's important, every bit."
>  "Bah," they say, "We know that slob. He is useless at our job.
>  He sulks and hides and rarely talks. He's certainly no chatterbo**x."
>
>  "Is** that a reason to exclude? To mock and joke and be so rude?
>  By himself he is not much," admits the Sergeant to the bunch.
>  "Everyone must help him be all that I know that he can be.
>  I know his task he will not shirk but, without you, he canno**t wo**rk!"
>  Here the Sergeant paused to think Where could that little guy have slinked?
>  Snorkeling at Sharktoo**th Ree**/**f? I've** never held such disbelief!
>  Diving of**f our** tallest peak? That cannot be the place I seek.
>  Wait a minute, I'm so dense! I needn't be in such suspense.
>  "If he's g**one** – walked out the door – he'**s even** more here than before!"
>  It was just then he realized the last had been here all the time.
>  The Sergeant spun until he spotted the space for little one allotted
>  Filled now - someone's in the spot. "There you are, you silly ___________!"

Comment: That's question 1 and 2. I was worried someone would say "ought" and we'd get into a discussion about word choice. For a +1, can you find all 9 members in the riddle? They're in there.

Comment: It's backwards and hanging on two lines.

Comment: Oh, hmm, I thought it was the 'vi' in 'Diving'.

Comment: If this is correct then #9 isn't actually hiding. >:(

Comment: @EngineerToast, I considered "ought" and "aught", which are both valid (but less common) words for zero as well, but I figured "naught" was less ambiguous.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: You know, you didn't really need to use "gone" for "one" -- the word "one" is literally in the rhyme! ;)

Comment: Was it the eight that tipped you off?

Comment: @Curmudgeon, I know, but I thought finding a "hidden" one would be more in the spirit, since it was there.

Comment: @JLee, yes, eight was the first one I found (aside from nine).

Comment: @dennisdeems 9 is much too proud of being the largest digit to want to *really* hide.

Comment: It didn't get mentioned, but I really like the line about zero being important, every bit. Get it? Bits. I'm hilarious.